# Proof verification: Cartesian Product of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I think I have this alright but I'm not 100% sure. I would appreciate any advice/critique. Thank you!

Show that $(A \cup B) \times C = (A\times C) \cup (B\times C)$

Proof : "$\Rightarrow$"

$(A\cup B) \times C \subset \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in (A\cup B)\  \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\cup B) \times C \subset \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in A \ \text{or} \  x\in B\ \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\cup B) \times C \subset  \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in A \ \text{and} \ c\in C \ \text{or} \  x\in B\  \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A \cup B) \times C \subset  \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in A \ \text{and} \ c\in C\} \cup \{(x,c) \ |\ x\in B\  \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\cup B) \times C \subset (A\times C) \cup (B\times C)\ \text{by definition}$

"$\Leftarrow$"

$(A\times C) \cup (B\times C) \subset \  \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in A \ \text{and} \ c\in C\} \cup \{(x,c) \ |\ x\in B\ , \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\times C) \cup (B\times C) \subset  \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in A \ \text{and} \ c\in C \ \text{or} \  x\in B\  \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\times C) \cup (B\times C) \subset \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in A \ \text{or} \  x\in B\ , \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\times C) \cup (B\times C) \subset \{(x,c)\ |\ x\in (A\cup B)\  \text{and}\  c\in C\}$

then $(A\times C) \cup (B\times C) \subset (A \cup B) \times C \   \text{by definition}$

Thus $(A \cup B) \times C = (A\times C) \cup (B\times C)$

Comment: FYI:  in this case, the $\times$ symbol does not represent a cross product (which is an operation on two 3-vectors), but the *Cartesian* product, which is a collection of ordered pairs.

Comment: Oops, silly me. Don't know why I wrote cross product lol.

Answer (score 1):

This proof seems fine, but this is a very unwieldy way to write it out. Normally, we would just say something like:

> "$\implies$"
>
> Suppose $(x,c)\in(A\cup B)\times C$. Then we have $x\in A\cup B$ and $c\in C$.....
>
> [omitted steps]
>
> ....thus we have $(x,c)\in (A\times C)\cup (B\times C)$. Therefore, $(A\cup B)\times C\subseteq (A\times C)\cup(B\times C)$.

and similarly for the other direction.

There's no need to write every single step out in set-builder notation.

Good job, though. You seem to have the general idea.

Comment: thanks! I used to get scolded for writing too many words in proofs using definitions so I went back to basics on this one. Glad to hear it looks good though!

Comment: Striking the right balance between words and symbols can be tricky, and it's hard to describe just where it is. Experience will be your best teacher there. :)